# Использование регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Нам даётся строка вида :
"5f3g2j(и т.д.)"
Надо вывести символы (f, g, j и т.д.) столько раз, сколько показывает числа(5,3,2 и т.д), стоящие до этих символов.
Мне хотелось бы использовать регулярные выражения, так как тема для меня новая. Также есть следующий код(нерабочий):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scn.nextLine();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[-]?[0-9]+([0-9]+)?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        int a = 0;

        for(int i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()); a < i ; a++) {
           System.out.println(input.charAt(matcher.end() + 1));
         }

      }  
}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете, в чём ошибка и, быть может, предложите свое решение)
Ошибка при присваивании переменной i в цикле for.

Answer (score 3):

Регулярными выражениями не намного сложнее:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern pat= Pattern.compile("\\G([0-9]++)([^0-9])"); // \\G для жесткого соответствия строки образцу "число повторений, символ"
        String text= "5x12e";
        StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();
        Matcher match= pat.matcher(text);
        while ( match.find() ) {
            for (int i=0; i<Integer.parseInt(match.group(1)); i++) {
                result.append(match.group(2));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/9Xsq6I

Comment: Угу, ваш вариант легче, мне вот пришлось `Integer` вручную парсить.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, мощь регулярных выражений тут не нужна, вы стреляете из пушки по воробьям.

Я бы сделал [так](http://ideone.com/DwG2Mv):

```
int repetitions = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        repetitions = c - '0';
    else
        for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            System.out.print(c);
}
```

---

[Вариант](http://ideone.com/xFalig) с (почти) такой же семантикой, как у [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus):

```
int repetitions = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        repetitions = 10 * repetitions + (c - '0');
    } else {
        for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++)
            System.out.print(c);
        repetitions = 0;
    }
}
```